# How to use multiple array index in $unwind using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following query where I am using same array index for three fields. But query response is incorrect because of using same arra index. Using query as follows

```
$pipeline = array(
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                'YPhaseVoltage' => 1,
                'RPhaseVoltage' => 1,
                'EventTS' => 1
            )
        ),          
        array(
            '$unwind' => array(
                'path' => '$RPhaseVoltage',
                'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
                'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$unwind' => array(
                'path' => '$YPhaseVoltage',
                'includeArrayIndex' => "arrayIndex",
                'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
            )
        ),
        array('$match' => array(
                '$and' => array(
                    array("RPhaseVoltage" => array('$ne' => null)),
                    array("YPhaseVoltage" => array('$ne' => null))
                )
    ),
        ),
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                '_id' => 0,
                'RPhaseVoltage' => 1,
                'YPhaseVoltage' => 1,
                'RYBTimestamp' => array(
                    '$add' => array(
                        array('$subtract' => array('$EventTS', $default_date)),
                        array('$multiply' => array( 60000, '$arrayIndex' )) 
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$project' => array(
                'rvoltage_data' => array('$RYBTimestamp', '$RPhaseVoltage'),
                'yvoltage_data' => array('$RYBTimestamp', '$YPhaseVoltage'),
                'RYBTimestamp' => 1
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$sort' => array('RYBTimestamp' => 1),
        ),
        array(
            '$limit' => 50
        )
);

$result = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

I want to use individual array index for each filed. Which gives me expected response. Please suggest me how to use multiple array index in mongodb aggregate?

Comment: you are trying to create three different array index fields for three different arrays but you are naming all three of them "arrayIndex".  Why don't you create a unique name for each of them?  Or maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish rather than how you are trying to do it.

Comment: also including a sample input document and sample expected output with explanation of what you are trying to do would help.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes, i am trying to create three different array index fields for three different arrays

Comment: then give each of them a different name.  The string is the field you want to hold the index.  Make it "arrayIndex1" "arrayIndex2" "arrayIndex3"